# How to edit this wordpress theme page using custom css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margin

Recently I've made a new `Wordpress` crew page for my team, [this one](http://www.cameradenmedia.nl/gif-test-2/). I'm using the visual composer plugin to put it all together. Unfortunately, the Wordpress theme adds a margin between the two sides that I cannot remove using visual composer. ([see here](https://ibb.co/ek75cd))

After using inspect element in Safari I found the line that creates the margin ([see here](https://ibb.co/bVWZLy)). After deleting the line it looks  ([like this](https://ibb.co/k3LfSd)).

My main question is: what is the best way to remove this margin? I'm afraid that jumping into the source code will mess up the website because the margin is part and connected to so many classes, maybe even on other pages?

Additional question: After deleting the margin in the inspector tool it creates white space on the right. I tried to find a specific page width or something similar but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You could create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Any code added to a child theme will not mess with the code of the original "Parent" theme. You can add your own stylesheet in it and override any styles you please, and they will carry over after any updates.

2. Use a plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) to inject your styles into the site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite whole column grid. Try pasting this CSS code on "Custom CSS" field of your template or use plugin like "Cusom CSS"

```
.vc_col-xs-12, .vc_col-sm-6 {margin-left:0px!important;}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body .vc_row-fluid .vc_col-sm-6 {width: 50%!important;}
}
```

If you know CSS, you should add ID to front page container and apply above CSS only to the front page. Otherwise it will take effect on whole website. It will remove margin between 1/2 columns.

Other way: 
Try to make same arrangement of elements by using full width table instead of responsive columns - it will affect how website will look on mobile devices - but do you like how it looks now on mobile? ;)